# How to clone --recursive using gcloud

Tags: gcloud

How do you clone submodules when using gcloud?

This does not work(note --recursive):

```
gcloud source repos clone <REP_NAME> --recursive --project=<PROJECT_NAME>
```

Also tried this, after cloning with this:

```
git fetch --recurse-submodules
```

And this:

```
git submodule init 
git submodule update
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gcloud source repos clone` command is a small wrapper around `git`, but it does not pass through all clone flags to `git`. If you run it with `--dry-run` flag

```
gcloud source repos clone <REP_NAME> --project=<PROJECT_NAME> --dry-run
```

it will print `git clone` command it uses under the hood. You can then run this command directly with `--recurse-submodules` flag (`--recursive` has been deprecated as of git 2.13).

Alternatively you can run `gcloud clone` and then use `git`

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Comment: The last command results in `git` asking for the username, probably because gcloud's credential helper does not get used.